# How can there be 8 pole trifasic motors? Shouldn't poles be a multiple of 6?

Tags: motor, induction-motor

How can there be trifasic motors with a number of poles non being a multiple of 6? I'd imagine poles in such motors would be 6 or 12 etc.

Comment: Isn't the number of poles the magnetic field poles? Ie, a 2 pole triphase motor has 6 coils, a 4pole has 12, etc

Answer (score 2):

The magnetic fields of three phases are combined to make each pair of poles.